# Semantic UI site.variables location?

Tags: python, html, css, django, semantic-ui

I have a Django/Python application and I want to use semantic UI in my views. I'm importing semantic using the CDN link, so my base HTML file has the following header...

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styles.css" %}">
...
</head
```

As you may see I want to load google fonts. However, all semantic UI elements seem to use the `Lato, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif` font by default and this is difficult to override.

All the advice I've seen online tells me to "**customize the `site.variables` file**". But where is this `site.variables` file? Is it something that I make, and if so, where do I put it so Semantic UI can detect it?

**UPDATE**: This is my CSS

```
html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your css.

Comment: Also you may want to use `pip install django-semantic-ui`

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I would like to continue using the CDN since I am just trying out semantic UI within my project. Is there any way to do this with the CDN link or do I have to `pip install`?

Comment: I should ve asked this earlier. Did you include {% load static %} at the top of your template?

Answer (score 0):

Error here.

```
href="{% static "styles.css" %}"
```

Should be `href="{% static 'AppName/styles.css' %}"`.

You can't you double quotes inside double quotes.

You may also like to use `django-semantic-ui`